# jquery 1.7.2 and jquery roundabout shapes not working in DotNetNuke

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

I've got a perculiar problem, I'm running DotNetNuke 6.2.2 and I'm using a normal HTML module on a page.  Within this page I'm adding images that then get manipulated with the jquery roundabout plugin.  In particular I'm trying to display the images as the waterWheel shape, http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout-shapes/, of the jquery roundabout shapes plugin.

The problem is this, if I'm logged into DNN as host, the animation displays correctly (waterWheel) but when I log out the images displays in the standard way: http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/demos/standard

I've read up on jquery 1.7.2 and there were some issues with the jquery roundabout plugin and jquery 1.7.2 but it seem to have been sorted out with jquery roundabout version 2.4.2 and jquery roundabout shapes Version 2.0, which I've now implemented in my DNN solution.

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Anina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much testing and time spent on this issue, I started to remove some js files that I includes on my skin page and low and behold when I removed the

```
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Resources/Shared/Scripts/jquery/jquery.hoverIntent.min.js" />
```

tag from my skin page it solved my problem.  It also doesn't seem to affect the backend for this skin, in terms of editing content, settings for different modules and such.

So I'm going to assume that this is what I had to remove, although I still don't know exactly what's in this file that would have caused my roundabout shapes jquery file not to fire the waterWheel shape, the only explanation could possibly be a clash in the jquery file.

If anyone could tell me what the issue could have been with this file being included on my skin page with my jquery.roundabout.js and jquery.roundabout-shapes.js files I'd be really grateful.

Thanks for the help Chris!

Comment: I seem to recall seeing hoverintent causing jquery issues myself, though I can't recall specifics

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at the javascript files (html source of the page) that are loaded when you are logged in as HOST versus the files that are loaded when you aren't logged in.

It sounds like a specific JS file isn't being loaded when you are not logged in, though I don't know which one.

Comment: Hi Chris, I've checked the javascript files that renders when I'm logging and and out and this is what I found, the only js files not loading when I'm logged out is: dnn.controls.dnnlabeledit.js, dnn.controls.dnntoolbar.js, dnn.controls.js, dnn.dom.positioning.js, dnn.xmlhttp.js, dnn.xmlhttp.jsxmlhttprequest.js, dnnactions.debug.js.  The rest of the files are exactly the same.  Could you spot anything significant that might be the cause of my problem?